# Vuejs not working with dynamic array, works perfectly with static array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I have

```
  data: {
    pictures: [
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?0',
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?1',
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?2',
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?3',
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?4',
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?5',
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?6',
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?7',
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?8',
      'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920?9',
    ]
  }
```

it renders perfectly, but when I fetch the data and get it like this in the console and perfect data in the vue dev tools

```
["https://picsum.photos/id/1020/4288/2848",
"https://picsum.photos/id/1021/2048/1206",
"https://picsum.photos/id/1022/6000/3376",
"https://picsum.photos/id/1023/3955/2094",
"https://picsum.photos/id/1024/1920/1280", 
__ob__: Observer]
```

it populates the dom but not rendered.

what am I missing??

Comment: How are you modifying the array? Are you replacing it, using `push`, modifying by index?

Comment: If I try to load the image in the browser, any of the picsum urls, nothing loads. Are you sure those picsum urls are correct?

Comment: Your question is really now clear, what are you trying to do? could you share more code so we could somehow grasp your issue?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I am cloning it using `this.newArray [...retrievedArray]`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky you may have copied wrong, but the pics URL work perfectly

Comment: @MyLibary so, what I'm trying to do is fetch image urls and populate that in my component. I have an html template that I got from themeforest and I am trying to break that into components and render my own data

Comment: what do you mean by 'it populates the dom but not rendered'

Comment: I can see the populated html items populated by the v-for directive which has a key

Comment: add v-model or add them in watch on `pictures`

Answer (score 0):

If I face that situation then I check if I have created that property as reactive.
Means I have added v-model on it or not.

Other way is to add it in watch propery as shown below

```
watch:{
    //just write name of the data propery and make it function
    picutres(){}
    //that's it
}
```

Now it will listen for the changes.

If you still somehow cannot fix that problem then other solution it to use `custom events` or a function

You will call function or trigger an event whenever you change your `pictures array`.
Then in function or event you can update your `pictures` array

Comment: I tried but it seems the classes from the `owl-carousel` are not working properly. I inspected in the browser & followed the `css` classes and it seems they are not updating as they do in my html template. I added the scripts in the `./public/index.html` in the `<script>` tag. Is that wrong? @Afraz-Ahmad